# Getting Environment Variables in Production (Vite& Vuejs3) with hidden .env File (.gitignore)

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I have built an app (vite vuejs) where I can access `.env` variables with the following `import.meta.env`

however, when I deploy the app, I can console log the environment's mode which is `production` but not any of the variables that I could previously get on my development mode

I am curious if having the `.env` file in my `.gitignore` makes them unreachable in production mode, and what is the solution to go about it where I can keep my variables hidden at the same time my deployed production environment updated with those variables.

Comment: Environment variables are provided _by the environment_. It's your production environment's responsibilty, not your code's or repo's, to provide the production env values. You will still need to do _something_ to set up the env variables.  Maybe command line parameters, or manually creating .env file on the prod server.  It will depend on your specific environment and whether it's a local server you control or some hosting service. If hosting service, there should be some documentation on recommended way of setting up env variables.

Comment: To add to the above comment, environment variables need to be defined at **build time**. How are you building and deploying your app?

Comment: The request to fetch the values will certainly be seen in the browser's dev tools network tab. It is not *that* hidden. gitignore will have nothing to do with it, it only applies to git. You can post code how you are doing this.